# ¿Como usar la caracteristica de modulos de Java 9 en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-9

Estoy tratando de aplicar el tema de módulos de Java 9 en un proyecto de Android Studio. Tengo 2 módulos:

1. app: Contiene el Framework Android
2. moduleOne: Un módulo que contiene solo código Java

[image: Módulos de la Aplicación]

Ahora como todos sabemos en el tema de módulos de Java 9, existe un archivo **module-info.java** que sirve para especificar que paquetes queremos que puedan ser exportados o que paquetes requerimos en el módulo. La idea es que para mi ejemplo solo quiero que mi **Módulo app** pueda acceder a solo el paquete common, por lo que el **module-info.java** se ve asi:
[image: module-info de moduleOne]

Ahora finalmente desde el **Módulo app** se debe especificar en su **module-info.java** que utilizará:
[image: module-info de app]

Obviamente que también se debe especificar en el build.gradle del **Módulo app**:

> implementation project(path: ':moduleOne')

Al terminar se logra el propósito original, el cual es que el **Modulo app** solo tenga acceso al paquete common de **moduleOne**, sin embargo al tratar de compilarlo no reconoce las especificaciones que el mismo Android Studio sugiere al momento de resolver las dependencias:

[image: dependencias irreconocibles]

Sin embargo, Android Studio habia sugerido agregar estas dependencias al **module-info.java**:
[image: dependencia relacionada a androidx]

[image: dependencia relacionada a android]

Sé que la solución esta relacionada al gradle:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular

Pero me es engorrosa la documentación y no me ayuda mucho, agradecería sus aportes.

Comment: Android no soporta java 9, solo una parte de java 8.

Comment: Si incluyo un modulo que depende del framework Android, no puedo compilar module-info.java, pero si creo otros módulos que dependan entre ellos sin usar el framework de android y usando module-info.java, funciona normalmente.
No me queda opción que recurrir a la herramienta de compilación **gradle** para hacer cumplir la encapsulación. Gracias por tu respuesta.